# Local Noetherian ring and sum of the power of its maximal ideal with another ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Well, I am trying to solve the next problem, which I found in a book of Commutative Algebra that mainly follows Atiyah's book and Eisenbud's book. The problem says:

> if $(R,m)$ is a local Noetherian ring and $ I $ an ideal with $\displaystyle \mathrm{rad}(I) \neq m $ show that $I+m^{n+1} $ is strictly contained in $m^n$, $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.

This exercise had also a first part which stated:

> if $\mathrm{Spec}(R)\neq \{0, m \} $ then show that $m^{n+1}$ is strictly contained in $m^n$.

I proved this part easily but I am stuck in the above question for more than 4 hours!
I have tried to use the fact that in a Noetherian ring there is a $t\in \mathbb{N}$ such as $(\mathrm{rad}(I))^t \subset I$  but I cannot see the next steps.

Can anybody help me with this?
Thank you a lot, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Assuming your question is the one in the second paragraph, it is false. For example let $R$ be a two dimensional regular local ring, with maximal ideal generated by $x,y$. The $\mathrm{rad}(xR)\neq \mathfrak{m}$. But, $xR+\mathfrak{m}^{n+1}$ is not contained in $\mathfrak{m}^n$ if $n>1$.

Comment: I don't get your question: $I+m^{n+1}\subsetneq m^n\implies I\subset m^n$. Is there a reason for $I\subset m^n$ for all $n$? (As far as I know, from Krull Intersection Theorem this leads to $I=(0)$.)

Comment: @user26857 :  Hmm..I see,yes indeed you are right. If we apply Krull's theorem, indeed $ I $ must be contained in every $m^n$ so I must be equal to ${0}$. Maybe something is written wrong inside the book, there are some typographical errors inside it, I will inform the professor who is also the author.

Comment: @Mohan Yes,maybe you are right. Unfortunately I still do not know what is a 2-dimensional local ring so I cannot confirm you are right. But, as user26857 mentioned, the above statement forces $ I $ to be equal to ${0}$. Ok,thanks a lot guys, probably there is a mistake in the book. If you have something else to notice, I would be very glad to hear it!